# Import from http:// quasar

Tags: javascript, json, vue.js, quasar-framework, quasar

Hi all I am doing quasar project and I need to access JSON file that is on server.

I'm trying this:
`Import MyVar from "http://myserver/files/MyVarfile.json"`

But whenever I try it it gives me error:

> The target environment doesn't support dynamic import() syntax so it's
> not possible to use external type 'module' within a script. Did you
> mean to build a EcmaScript Module ('output.module: true')?

Comment: Try without `http://myserver`?

Comment: Then it throws error: "Module not found: can't resolve import dependency"

Comment: Use the correct page to the JSON file? We cannot tell you what that is.

Comment: Yeah I definitely use the correct page checked that with CTR + click it opens the right file in the browser, but I was thinking it migh something to do with configuration files, because it only throws this error of in trying to acces files that are on server but no issue when I acces the same file but just copied it on my desktop.